# Method TraceFlagList::Add(TraceFlag* flag) of gRPC trace.cc makes its chained list loop to itself

Tags: c++, grpc

I am integrating gRPC for a 32-bit Atom hardware. gRPC is cross-compiled on a 64-bit Ubuntu PC computer. The cross-compilation uses Yocto. The CMakeLists.txt file of gRPC is included into the main project with add_subdirectory() function, and linked in static. To test gRPC, I use the C++ speech sample code of Google.

The complete project builds correctly and is deployed on the target hardware without problem. When I run the sample program, the execution is stucked in an infinite loop in the method TraceFlagList::Set(const char* name, bool enabled) of the file trace.cc.

To check the problem, I put some printf() in this method, in every loop:

```
bool TraceFlagList::Set(const char* name, bool enabled) {
  TraceFlag* t;
  if (0 == strcmp(name, "all")) {
    for (t = root_tracer_; t; t = t->next_tracer_) {
      printf("%s 1 %s\n", __func__, t->name_);
      t->set_enabled(enabled);
    }
  } else if (0 == strcmp(name, "list_tracers")) {
    LogAllTracers();
  } else if (0 == strcmp(name, "refcount")) {
    for (t = root_tracer_; t; t = t->next_tracer_) {
      printf("%s 2 %s\n", __func__, t->name_);
      if (strstr(t->name_, "refcount") != nullptr) {
        t->set_enabled(enabled);
      }
    }
  } else {
    bool found = false;
    for (t = root_tracer_; t; t = t->next_tracer_) {
      printf("%s 3 %s\n", __func__, t->name_);
      if (0 == strcmp(name, t->name_)) {
        t->set_enabled(enabled);
        found = true;
      }
    }
    // check for unknowns, but ignore "", to allow to GRPC_TRACE=
    if (!found && 0 != strcmp(name, "")) {
      gpr_log(GPR_ERROR, "Unknown trace var: '%s'", name);
      return false; /* early return */
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

It appears that some TraceFlag pointers are added several times in the TraceFlagList object. Here is the add method:

```
void TraceFlagList::Add(TraceFlag* flag) {
  flag->next_tracer_ = root_tracer_;
  root_tracer_ = flag;
}
```

The first element to add has its next_tracer_ member pointing to null. But after several adding, TraceFlagList::Add() is called again with the same TraceFlag pointers. The first one will have its next_tracer_ member pointing to the last element of list, making the list loop onto itself.

Running the executable displays these lines in the command line:

```
...
Set 3 api
Set 3 timer_check
Set 3 timer
Set 3 resource_quota
Set 3 executor
Set 3 bdp_estimator
Set 3 client_idle_filter
Set 3 cares_resolver
Set 3 cares_address_sorting
Set 3 round_robin
Set 3 pick_first
Set 3 xds
Set 3 glb
Set 3 inproc
Set 3 health_check_client
Set 3 secure_endpoint
Set 3 http2_stream_state
Set 3 flowctl
Set 3 http
Set 3 connectivity_state
Set 3 tcp
Set 3 http1
Set 3 handshaker
Set 3 channel
Set 3 subchannel_pool
Set 3 subchannel
Set 3 client_channel_routing
Set 3 client_channel_call
Set 3 tsi
Set 3 plugin_credentials
Set 3 server_channel
Set 3 queue_pluck
Set 3 op_failure
Set 3 compression
Set 3 call_error
Set 3 api
Set 3 timer_check
Set 3 timer
Set 3 resource_quota
Set 3 executor
Set 3 bdp_estimator
Set 3 client_idle_filter
Set 3 cares_resolver
Set 3 cares_address_sorting
^C
```

I have to break the executable with ctrl+c to stop it. I made a workaround by checking first the existence of the element to add in the list:

```
void TraceFlagList::Add(TraceFlag* flag) {
  // Check TraceFlag existence in the list before adding it.
  for (const TraceFlag* t = root_tracer_; t != nullptr; t = t->next_tracer_) {
    if (t == flag) {
      gpr_log(GPR_DEBUG, "\t%s", t->name_);
      printf("TraceFlag %s already in TraceFlagList. Ignore.\n", t->name_);
      return;
    }
  }

  flag->next_tracer_ = root_tracer_;
  root_tracer_ = flag;
}
```

But this is a workaround: when building and running the original code for the Ubuntu host, there is no problem of infinite loop. Each TraceFlag pointer is added only once. And I don't really know what TraceFlag are used for in gRPC.

I am afraid that the workaround could hides the real problem, which could have unexpected side effects. Does anybody have any clue to the origin of this problem ? Or should I propose this workaround the gRPC project ?

Regards.

Comment: you can also `export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG` and `export GRPC_TRACE=list_tracers` (replace export with set for windows) to see the infinite list (much like the logging in the question) without any grpc code changes.

I'm using a 32-bit version on a 32-bit centos vm

Answer (score 0):

This looks like https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20690
grpc core uses some globals and if you have multiple version of the grpc library linked in somehow, the globals get corrupted.